# rsocket can't run separate tab in my browser

Tags: angular, spring-boot, rsocket, rsocket-java, rsocket-js

I have a demo app front-end using angular.

I'm using Rsocket and resumeable for the community with my server-side (spring-boot).

It runs very well when I open a single tab in my browser but when I open a new tab while the current tab still keeps then I get a problem.

[current tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAZ8Z.png)

[new tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmQKg.png)

[current tab after open new tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/giITI.png)

Rsocket'state in the new tab is connected while rsocket'state in the previous tab is closed.

=> How can I keep my Rsocket run separate tab in my browser?

Comment: have you found an answer for this?

Comment: i figured it out. because i used a static resume token. you just make unique resume token for each tab then this proplem will be done.

Comment: thanks! just curious, are you using rsocket over http1.1?

Comment: i'm using rsocket over websocket. what version of http along websocket depend libs.